# How to change the number of columns in Bootstrap grid with Laravel and JQuery Masonry

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry, masonry

I know little about Laravel and Masonry grid layout, but I know how Bootstrap framework works.

I need to change the number of columns in a Boostrap grid for small size devices like a mobile phone. Currently, the number of columns is 3 because the class used is `col-xs-4`. However, I need to change it to `col-xs-6`, so that it shows 2 columns.

I don't think it's that hard, but I don't know how Laravel works.

I tried searching for those divs in the whole project so that I could directly change those classes, but I couldn't find anything.

This is an example of one column in a row:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fw-divider-space hidden-below-xl pt-70"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div data-animation="fadeInDown" class="row isotope-wrapper masonry-layout c-gutter-5 c-mb-5 animate animated fadeInDown" style="position: relative; height: 798px;">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-lgx-3 col-xl-3 col-xs-4 col-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
                    <div class="vertical-item item-gallery content-absolute text-center ds">
                        <a href="https://www.tusencuentros.cl/modelo/9/ver" class="item-media h-100 w-100 d-block"><img src="https://www.tusencuentros.cl/storage/fotos_perfil/9-1.jpg" alt="Modelo">
                            <div class="media-links"></div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=56946717880" target="_blank" style="background-color: transparent;"><img src="https://clubvip.cl/storage/watsapp_logo.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-top: 5px;"></a> <a href="tel:+56946717880" target="_blank" style="background-color: transparent;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-phone-square" style="font-size: 36px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); float: right;"></i></a>
                        <div class="item-content" style="background-color: rgb(233, 11, 165);">
                            <div class="item-title" style="top: -80px; width: 100%;">
                                <div style="display: inline-flex;">
                                    <p style="font-size: 14px;">CARLITA </p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p style="font-size: 12px;">CHILENA, 20</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p style="font-size: 10px;">Medidas: 94-62-98</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the classes `col-xs-4` to be `col-xs-6`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use laravel blade

You can use dynamic css class in here like

```
class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-lgx-3 col-xl-3 {{ $isMobile ? 'col-xs-6' : 'col-xs-4' }} col-4"
```

In the curly blackets : is this mobile device? if yes, I will use **col-xs-6** if not I will use **col-xs-4**

But you need to send the checking of $isMobile from your controller and there is a very simple component for that [here jenssegers/agent](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent)

After installation you can perform check for mobile device by using **$agent->isMobile()** method

Comment: What if I just want to keep it as `col-xs-6`? how can I do it in that case?

Comment: @DavidM Hey sorry but I don't understand your question. a bit more information please?

Comment: I don't want to use a dynamic css with the curly brackets like you said. I just want to change the class `col-xs-4` to `col-xs-6` in that div because it's simpler I think. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could fix it by finding out that the folder with the file that contains those divs was inside a non-public location called "resources". Since I know little about Laravel Blade, I didn't know the directory structure.